# Как запретить в WPF DataGrid добавлять ряды с пустыми полями?

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF имеется datagrid, к которому подключен через ItemsSourse список объектов. CanUserAddRows="True", вбиваем значения в ячейки нового пустого ряда, жмем Enter и списку в памяти добавляется объект с соответствующими значениями свойств. Но если не вбивать значения в поля а просто несколько раз жать Enter, то добавятся объекты с пустыми свойствами. Как запретить добавление пустых рядов или хотя бы как отловить момент, когда объект уже готов создаться, чтобы проверить его свойства и не разрешить datagrid его добавить?

Comment: Мне кажется надо работать так : сбор данных , подготовка данных и работа с данными. валидируйте объект, до того как он попадет в коллекцию которая привязана к datagrid.

Comment: Вопрос и сводится к тому, что я не знаю как поймать этот момент, а даже если поймать - как запретить добавлять пустой объект к коллекции?

Comment: у вас же есть метод который порождает сущность и добавляет её в коллекцию ? Проверяйте перед добавлением её поля.

Comment: Никакого метода нет, иначе не было бы и этого вопроса. Сущность порождает сам datagrid, когда я жму Enter, находясь в нижней пустой строке, которая до нажатия имеет тип NewItemPlaceholder

Comment: Может лучше добавить отдельную кнопку и при ее нажатии проверять заполнены поля или нет?

Answer (score 1):

В ивенте CellValueChanged/CellEditEnding добавь проверку на пустоту во всех ячейках Row. Если все ячейки пустые -- отменяй действие.

Comment: Если используется какой либо паттерн относительно всей архитектуры приложения, можно просто вписать валидацию объекта относительно его полей на null or empty, иногда помогает, чтобы не аттачится ко всем евентам контролов.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, это если используется как виртуальный) В случае когда данные сохраняются в сам DataGridView -- прийдется проверять именно ячейки. Вряд ли автор вопроса использует его в виртуальном режиме.

Comment: Не вижу у WPF DataGrid эвента CellValueChanged

Comment: ну тогда CellEditEnding

Comment: CellEditEnding и RowEditEnding не подходят: если к примеру взять в этом обработчике e.Row.Item и привести к нужному типу, то значения всех свойств пустые, даже если я перед нажатием на enter ввел значение. Т.е. при обработке этих событий datagrid уже создал объект, но еще не заполнил его свойства.

Comment: А CurrentCellChangED пробовал?

Answer (score 0):

Оформлю свои мысли как полноценный ответ : если вы работаете с валидацией каких либо данных, работайте по принципу : `сбор данных -> обработка данных -> работа с данными.` Каждый шаг в этой цепочке уменьшает шанс появление ошибки в последующем шаге.

А по поводу данного вопроса, относительно `DataGrid`. В методе где Вы производите какие либо изменения относительно полей объекта или добавление нового объекта, обязательно включите какой нибудь метод : `public bool IsValid()`, чтобы проверять то что должно пойти в коллекцию. Опять таки если Вы используете какой нибудь паттерн (MVC, MVP, MVVM), вы можете описать валидирование в рамках паттерна.

Например очень хороший вопрос насчет валидации в рамках MVVM : [Proper validation with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498485/proper-validation-with-mvvm)